# MongoDB - Archiving GridFS files (via TTL)

Tags: mongodb

I know I can set a TTL index on the files collection using:

```
db.files.ensureIndex({"uploadDate" : 1},{expireAfterSeconds : XXX})
```

The problem is, that it doesn't handle the db.chunks collection.
So I can create background job that will go over the db.chunks and look for orphans but it misses the point, since if I must have a background job, I could just let him do all the work and it would probably even be faster (I can bulk the deletion from the chunks more easily).

So, is there any smarter way of archiving\deleting files from the GridFS after a predefined period of time?

Thanks

Comment: TTL indexes rely on the presence of a "Date" type field in order for the default scheduled process to check. Since the "chunks" collection does not have this then your removal is a manual process. You can create your own schedule to do so. But MongoDB does not maintain "referential integrity" by design. I'm posting this as a comment because it really should not require an answer to help other in future. I expect someone will answer much the same nonetheless unless you choose to delete.

Comment: There is a fundamental difference between archiving and deleting documents. Please elaborate your actual use case (programming language, framework, business logic) so that we can help you.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg - Why? whether it will move the data to a different collection\store or completely delete it - both actions require some sort of a mark & sweep operation.

Comment: @NeilLunn - I know the chunks collection doesn't have a date field, the question is if there's no way to create a js method that the TTL infra will use as part of it's sweep operation

Comment: The TTL functionality is a process that scans known indexes for the definition of this "expires" property. It requires a "date type" to be present on the referenced field. As Already stated, anything that falls outside of this functionality is your own scheduled service to code. And I have already stated that the existing documentation is quite clear on this, which is way the format is not as an answer. Answered questions should provide future use. What you are asking can be determined by reading the documentation.